# factorial - "working structure"

Tags: c#-4.0

Please, if someone helped me here I would be extremely gratefull!

Here is simple code for factorial:

```
using System;
namespace CalculatorApplication
{
   class NumberManipulator
   {
      public int factorial(int num)
      {
         /* local variable declaration */
     int result;
     if (num == 1)
     {
        return 1;
     }
     else
     {
        result = factorial(num - 1) * num;
        return result;
     }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     NumberManipulator n = new NumberManipulator();
     //calling the factorial method
     Console.WriteLine("Factorial of 6 is : {0}", n.factorial(5));

     Console.ReadLine();
  }
}
}
```

OK, my quuestion is how do we achieve to get right factorial (f.e. from 5 we get 5*4*3*2*1. 
Why don't we get 5*4=20 or:

5*4 *
4*3 *
3*2 *
2*1  *
1*1  hwo do we "miss" here pair 4*3 - how does the processor KNOW that right that pair is to be missed- in other words, shortly, how and where processor REMEMBERS numbers we have to multiply (5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ) WITHOUT A KIND OF LOOP

P.s. I could understand clearly what is happening IF ther was a kind of noraml LOOP, but I just dont understand it "rewritten" as recursion...please, if someone could make it clear step by step what is happening in processor's head...MANY MANY THANKS!!!- I am not sure that is an easy  question!!!!

Answer (score 0):

First: this will error on `public int factorial(int num)` method you'll receive a local variable error.

Second: You cannot achieve a factorial without using a loop since user input is dynamic.  If you wanna do recursion, you will still use loop to iterate through the recursion.

Hence the processor reads the code from top to bottom, left to right EXCEPT for some programming languages example is C#, it will start reading from the `Main()` method (with the capital **M**). So if you create a method `public string main()`, this will not give you error, but it will still begin reading from the `Main()`.